# lambda function not working

Tags: java, lambda

Using this

```
private static void method (MyClass mc, int num){
    System.out.println(mc.operation(num));
}
private static interface Exec{
    public int operation(int num);
}
static abstract class MyClass implements Exec{}
```

I am able to call the method using

```
method(new MyClass(){
    public int operation(int num) {return num*2;}
}, 15);
```

but when I am using a lambda `method(a->a*2, 15);` I have 2 errors :

> *The target type of this expression must be a functional interface*

, and

> *The method ... is not applicable for the arguments (( a) - > {}, int)*

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas can only implement interfaces, they *cannot* extend abstract classes.  If your `method` had signature

```
public static void method(Exec mc, int num)
```

then it would probably work.  I strongly suspect both errors are the result of that issue.